# Downvotes: How can I learn to hear an octave-displaced popular piece, as easily as the popular piece?

Tags: discussion

Why was [How can I learn to hear an octave-displaced popular piece, as easily as the popular piece?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/69330/26407) downvoted? [This comment](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/69330/how-can-i-learn-to-hear-an-octave-displaced-popular-piece-as-easily-as-the-popu#comment107245_69330) states:

> I've downvoted as it's not a good question - we don't know what's going on in your mind.

But asking how to learn or know something, [is on-topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=how%20to%20hear). The reason overhead can be stated for any of these questions that are centered on the questioner.

[How can a non-musician recognize anacrusis?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/36411/26407)
[How can I train my ear for music?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/98/26407)
[How can I generate nice-sounding random chord progressions?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/how-can-i-generate-nice-sounding-random-chord-progressions?s=29|0.0000)
[How can I toughen up my fingertips?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/289/26407)

Answer (score 6):

Voters are under no obligation to explain their votes, but in the general case, the voting guidance on our help page states:

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information. The more that people vote on a post, the more certain future visitors can be of the quality of information contained within that post – not to mention that upvotes are a great way to thank the author of a good post for the time and effort put into writing it!

As mentioned to you many times on this and other sites, it doesn't matter that an individual downvoted your post and not someone else's that you think is similar. They may not think that. Or they may not have seen it. Or any number of reasons. Similarly, people upvote without giving reasons.

TL:Dr there is rarely any point asking why you got down votes. If people comment with a reason please take that on board. If they don't, assume something in line with the help page quote above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe I voted on this question.

As stated now, it looks perfectly OK to me, although I haven't watched the videos.

Answer (score 0):

I think sometimes we *are* guilty on this site of downvoting / voting to close questions that are logically reasonable but in practice hard to answer, and that might be said to apply somewhat here; I imagine there may well be techniques that would help you recognise scale degrees irrespective of octave, but it may be that your problem isn't a commonly-encountered one, and that there therefore isn't a commonly-known way of solving it.

As Dr Mayhem points out, 'good' questions are also supposed to be well-researched - and it could be said that it's hard to see from your question what you've already done to try to solve your own problem.

Overall, though, I don't really see the problem with your question.

If I'm honest, I think another factor is that you do now have something of a history of posting some quite borderline questions on this site. That may be simply because your areas of musical interest don't quite fit with this site's scope, but given that each off-topic question takes time and effort to clean up, you can appreciate that people may start to have negative associations with your username and be inclined *not* to give your questions the benefit of the doubt. I've personally spent a lot of time *defending* at least one of your questions in the past, and I don't think it's ideal that we should assess things in 'personal' terms, but we are a community and it is natural to pick up on how each person is acting as part of the community.

Comment: Personally I don't understand the question in question at all, and it sounds like the question is about the asker's inability to understand auditory information. If that's what the question is about, I'm not sure that it's really related to music at all (perhaps psychology?) and how any of us could answer it in any case. Imagine a question asking why the colors blue and orange look the same. Maybe the asker is color blind or the lighting is bad, but even on the photography or physics sites they couldn't help beyond that.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I think I see what you're saying there, but I think the question could be interpreted more objectively - to recognise the tune as happy birthday (which was the OP's wish), you could say that the skill required is to be able to recognise intervals or scale degrees, both of which could be ear training questions at heart (which we do allow some of).

Comment: Thanks for your honest feedback that I'll heed.